# While creating envelope and bulk list I'm getting response: "size":0,"timeout":0, status: 201, statusText: 'Created'

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

Why don't I get the envelopeId for POST envelopes
and in the second request listId for POST bulk_send_lists?
My goal is bulk send.
My POST for new envelope looks like:

```
app.post("/envelopes", async (req, res) => {                    
    let accountId = req.query.accountId;
    let accessToken = req.query.accessToken;
    try {
        const response = await fetch(baseURL + "restapi/v2.1/accounts/" + accountId +"/envelopes", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",                
                "Accept": "*/*",
                "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"                
            },            
            body: JSON.stringify(req.body)
        });
        const data = await response;        
        res.json(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.json({ error })
    }
});
```

req.body for a new envelope looks like:

```
{
  status: 'created',
  emailSubject: 'Sign document',
  templateId: '********-****-****-***-************',    
}
```

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1):

The code you shared here is to create a single envelope, not a bulk list. It is set to create it based on a template (you provided **templateId**), but you may need to provide recipients, which you didn't provide, based on a **roleName** property (**TemplatesRoles** object)

[Here is Node.js code](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node/blob/master/lib/eSignature/examples/useTemplate.js) to send an envelope based on a template.

[Here is Node.js code](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node/blob/master/lib/eSignature/examples/bulkSendEnvelope.js) to send a bulk send request.

Comment: I succeeded based on the link you posted. Thank you very much!